# Creating a rank for "Order By" integer data - MySQL

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm working on a project where I have some attendance data. I want to be able to print the top # attendees.

My query as is is set to order the list by # of events attended for each individual. I allow the user to set a limit (so, say top 50 attendees). The problem is that this doesn't do anything to account for ties, so I want to generate a rank in the query that I can then use to limit by.

My relevant schema is as follows:

Members Table:

```
Member Name | Member ID | # Events Attended
```

Events Table:

```
Event Name | Event ID | Other Stuff
```

This table is then used as a foreign key for an attendance table, which links members to events by using a foreign key that combines a Member and Event ID.

Attendance Table:

```
Attendance Log ID | Member FK | Event FK
```

So, my query as is is this:

```
SELECT  `Member Name`, `Member ID` , COUNT(  `Member ID` ) AS Attendances
FROM  `Members` m
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT *
 FROM  `Events` e
 INNER JOIN  `Attendance` r ON  `Event ID` =  `Event FK`
) er
ON  `Member ID` =  `Member FK`
GROUP BY  `Member ID`
ORDER BY `Attendances` DESC
```

So, to summarize, **how can I create a "rank" that I can use to limit results? So top 50 attendees is top 50 ranked attendees (so #entries >= 50), rather than 50 individuals (# entries always 50, cuts off ties).**

Thanks all!

Edit1:

Sample output from query with no limit (show all results):

```
Member Name | Member ID | Attendances
Bob Saget               1                    5
John Doe                2                    4
Jane Doe                3                    3
Stack Overflow          4                    3
```

So, when users request "Show top 3 attendees" with my current query, 
they would get the following:

```
Member Name | Member ID | Attendances
Bob Saget               1                    5
John Doe                2                    4
Jane Doe                3                    3
```

when in reality, I'd like it to display the ties and show something like

```
Rank | Member Name | Member ID | Attendances
1             Bob Saget              1               5
2             John Doe               2               4
3             Jane Doe               3               3
3             Stack Overflow         4               3
```

Comment: Plz post sample data and expected O/P.

Comment: Ankit - added an edit that I think (if I interpreted correctly) should provide the information you're looking for. Excuse my troubles with formatting. Trying to figure it out.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on one thing. Do you want all duplicate counts to be considered a single rank, or just once we've reached the rank of '50' any additional ones of the same rank still get included?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT IF(Attendances = @_last_Attendances, @curRank:=@curRank, @curRank:=@_sequence) AS rank, 
       @_sequence:=@_sequence+1,@_last_age:=age, Member Name, Member ID, 
       COUNT(  `Member ID` ) AS Attendances     
FROM `Members` m
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM  `Events` e
            INNER JOIN  `Attendance` r 
            ON  `Event ID` =  `Event FK`) er
ON  `Member ID` =  `Member FK`, 
(SELECT @curRank := 1, @_sequence:=1, @_last_Attendances:=0) r
GROUP BY  `Member Name`, `Member ID`, Rank
HAVING COUNT( `Member ID`) >= (SELECT MAX (`Member ID`) 
                               FROM `Members`
                               WHERE `Member ID` < (SELECT MAX (`Member ID`)  
                                                    FROM `Members`
                                                    WHERE `Member ID` < (SELECT MAX (`Member ID`)  
                                                                         FROM `Members`)))
    ORDER BY COUNT(`Member ID`) DESC;
```

I think this approach will help you.

Comment: I ran it in PHPMyAdmin and got an error:  #1054 - Unknown column 'Attendances' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in two queries is going to be your best bet, otherwise the query gets really convoluted.

[Here is a SQLFiddle showing your table schema, example data, and the queries we're talking about.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2d5b/1)

The first problem we need to break down is how to determine what the correct rank is. We can do this by doing the select but only returning a single value of the rank that is our new limit. Assuming we want the top 3 ranks we'll return only the third row (offset 2, limit 1).

```
# Pre-select the lowest rank allowed.
SELECT COUNT(a.attendanceId) INTO @lowestRank
FROM  Member AS m
  JOIN Event AS e
  JOIN Attendance AS a USING (memberId, eventId)
GROUP BY m.memberId
ORDER BY 'Attendances' DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2;
```

Once we have the `@lowestRank` we can now run the query again but with a `HAVING` clause to restrict the `GROUP BY` results. By restricting only results which have a rank equal to or greater than the `@lowestRank` we've essentially added a `LIMIT` to that field.

```
# Return all rows of the lowest rank or above.
SELECT m.name, m.memberId, COUNT(a.attendanceId) AS 'Attendances'
FROM  Member AS m
  JOIN Event AS e
  JOIN Attendance AS a USING (memberId, eventId)
GROUP BY m.memberId
HAVING COUNT(a.attendanceId) >= @lowestRank
ORDER BY 'Attendances' DESC;
```

We could have done this in one query by making the first one a JOIN of the second one, but I don't recommend that because it complicates the queries, has potential performance impact, and makes it harder to change them independently.

For example the first query only limits duplicates at the cutoff point, but if you wanted to consider all duplicates a single rank then we could change that query to only consider `DISTINCT` rows. In this particular data set the results would be the same, but if we had two members with four attendance then we'd still get three distinct ranks (5, 4, 4, 3, 3) versus the above query only gets two distinct ranks (5, 4, 4).